# Query to Get the last inserted row from a dynamic table grouping by one field

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

How can we write the query for getting a set of rows where it was last updated grouped by a field name . Example

no - siteid - status - created_at

the 'no' number increases continuously as its the status report provided from another source. As in , Insertion happens 24/7 at some interval. But i want to check the status of 10 sites at the second i run the query .

There are only 10 sites . and i want to generate the report of the status of these 10

as in the last inserted query will give us the current status of the site.

I tried this

```
SELECT created_at,siteid  FROM [TOC].[dbo].[frame1] GROUP BY siteid ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

But no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not actually sure what you want, can you give example input and output data?

For now here is something that *might* be useful to you...

```
WITH
  sequenced_data AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY site_id ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS sequence_id,
    *
  FROM
    [TOC].[dbo].[Frame1]
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  sequenced_data
WHERE
  sequence_id = 1
```

Comment: Input query. get a data set with the current status of all the sites if its running or not at this moment ( last inserted row about one site )

Comment: This suggestion gets one record per site, across all sites, selected by it having the highest created_at value for that site.